# Doctrine - ManyToMany with custom primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I've a unidirectional ManyToMany relation:

```
class Account {
    /* other attributes ... */
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item")
     * @ORM\JoinTable("account_items",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="vnum")}
     *     )
     */
    private $items;
}
```

**What I want to do:**
I would like to make the account possible to have one or more identical Item (the same identifier.). For example:

```
`account_id` 1, `item_id` 1
`account_id` 1, `item_id` 1
```

should've been allowed.

It's not possible when doctrine generates DDL query with two primary keys (account_id, item_id) and if I try to do it I got mysql duplciation entry error.

I customized migration that creates `id` as primary key (as only one), but I think it's not proper solution.

```
`id`: 1, account_id` 1, `item_id` 1
`id` : 2, account_id` 1, `item_id` 1
```

Do you have any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a bi-directionnal OneToMany <=> ManyToOne relation between 3 entities.

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Account.php**</kbd>

```
class Account {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\AccountItem", mappedBy="accounts")
     */
    private $accountItems;
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/AccountItem.php**</kbd>

```
class AccountItem {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="accountItems")
     */
    private $accounts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="itemAccounts")
     */
    private $items;
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Item.php**</kbd>

```
class Item {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\AccountItem", mappedBy="items")
     */
    private $itemAccounts;
}
```

It's in fact a ManyToMany relation, but you can now add `id`, which will be unique, en still have duplicate entries.

Side now, you're referencing `item.vnum` in your annotation. Know that Symfony hate it when you don't use `id`.